# Trying to play one sound on tapping on an image

Tags: xaml, uwp

Hi I'm trying to play a sound on tapping of an image but it is not playing.
Actually here i'm also using one media element to play a sound on this page continuously. It is playing but other which should be played on tapping of image is not playing.Any idea would be appreciated.

Xaml code

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mycontrol" Source="/Audio/bg_sound.mp3"  AutoPlay="True"/>
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement1" />
```

C# Code

```
   public sealed partial class Home : Page
        {
            public Home()
            {
                this.InitializeComponent();

            }

            private void L_color_tap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                mediaElement1.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Objectnamesmp3/colors.mp3");
                mediaElement1.AutoPlay = true;
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(L_Col_Act));

            }  
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mycontrol" Source="/Audio/bg_sound.mp3"  AutoPlay="True"/>
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement1"  Source="/Assets/LearnColor/Objectnamesmp3/colors.mp3" AutoPlay="False" />
```

And in c# code you can change it to

```
public sealed partial class Home : Page
    {
        public Home()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void L_color_tap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mycontrol.Stop();
            mediaElement.Play();               

        }  
    }
```

and this [**this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(L_Col_Act));**]  Navigation code can go in your media ended Event for mediaElement1.
Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Only one MediaElement allowed to play at a time.

Please refer to this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202883(v=vs.105).aspx